# Parallelism during usage of UDF in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a UDF based on a jar. We need to pass few parameters to UDF, based on which UDF returns data.

When we have multi worker spark cluster with autoscaling, would UDF takes benefit of spark parallelism, or it always runs on single worker? I noticed that during my runs, the spark code is always using 1D and 1 Worker, no additional workers.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION udf_function_name AS 'j.hive.udtf.udf_function_name';

create or replace view result_data as select udf_function_name("user","password","report", "Last 2 Days")

create table final_name as select * from result_data;
```

Comment: Spark UDF functions can process data in parallel. If you have a DataFrame with multiple partitions, Spark can apply the UDF to each partition concurrently. Please check if your data is not partitioned correctly.

Comment: thanks. Basically in my case udf is invoking few APIs to source the data. Data is not in any cloud storage. So to confirm, in general , the UDFs in spark can utilize spark parallelism?

Comment: yes, if the UDF is using spark native functions on the data pulled from the APIs it can process in parallel